# String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema. Estaba haciendo el dibujo en la consola para el juego ahorcado, pero al dibujar las manos del muñeco de siguiente manera:
System.out.println(" |           /||\"); obtengo el siguiente error: "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote". ¿Como puedo corregir el error sin modificar el dibujo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mano `\` es precisamente el carácter que se usa para preceder [cualquier secuencia de escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), tales como `\t` : tabulador, `\n`: nueva línea, etc.

Cuando necesites mostrarlo a él mismo, tienes que escaparlo consigo mismo :)

Por ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(" | /||\\");
```

**Salida:**

```
 | /||\
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!